# Moodle how to find out the role of the logged in user

Tags: php, moodle

How to get context/role of logged in user in moodle?
I am trying to implement a context-aware block. The block would suggest the right quizzes to its users based on their moods.

Role can be a teacher, student, teacher assistant or admin. I have already found the `get_context_instance()` & `has_compatibility()` functions, but I don't know how to use them for this purpose.

Comment: Roles and contexts are one of the most complicated concepts in Moodle, but the short version is a context generally applies to a single course, a single category, or the whole site. A role is granted within that context, and assigns capabilities to the user within that context.

Answer (score 10):

checking user is an admin or not

```
$admins = get_admins();
$isadmin = false;
foreach($admins as $admin) {
    if ($USER->id == $admin->id) {
        $isadmin = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

use the result for functions

```
if ($isadmin) {
    echo "you are an admin";    
} else { 
    echo "you are not an amidn";
}
```

Comment: This works very well, thanks for sharing. Swapped break for a custom CSS file load.

Comment: `is_siteadmin()`  is enough to identify an admin.

Answer (score 9):

```
$context = get_context_instance (CONTEXT_SYSTEM);
$roles = get_user_roles($context, $USER->id, false);
$role = key($roles);
$roleid = $roles[$role]->roleid;
```

it works to me

Answer (score 6):

In Moodle 2.x you may use the function `get_user_roles` and this will return list of roles assigned to a particular user in context of course or site or module.

```
$context = get_context_instance(CONTEXT_COURSE, $courseid, true);
$roles = get_user_roles($context, $USER->id, true);
```

You can also get the roles in context of module.

```
$context = get_context_instance(CONTEXT_MODULE, $cm->id, true);
$roles = get_user_roles($context, $USER->id, true);
```

Answer (score 3):

In moodle the roles are based on the context. 
I think this code snippet will be helpful for you.

global $COURSE, $USER;

```
$context = get_context_instance(CONTEXT_COURSE,$COURSE->id);

if (has_capability('moodle/legacy:student', $context, $USER->id, false) ) {
echo "Student";
}

if (has_capability('moodle/legacy:editingteacher', $context, $USER->id, false)) {
echo "is Teacher<br/>";
}
if (has_capability('moodle/legacy:admin', $context, $USER->id, false)) {
echo "is ADMIN<br/>";
}
```

Bear in mind that it is perfectly possible (but unlikely) to have a Moodle site without the default Student and Teacher roles

Comment: This code is good, but there is a problem. Since I'm not in the view/course suppose I'm in the homepage and I want to find out what's the role. this won't work

Answer (score 1):

You can test for which roles a user has in the following manner:

```
if (user_has_role_assignment($user1->id, $roleid))
    echo "User is a teacher in some course";
```

The role id of a teacher is usually 3, and the role id of a student is usually 5, but you can test this looking at the table in Site Administration-> Users -> Permissions -> Define Roles

Please note that one user can have various roles. The function user_has_role_assignment seems to test of which roles he has system wide.

Answer (score 0):

include the library 'accesslib.php' and then use the 'is_siteadmin()' function